# Two strings - what is better?

Tags: java, performance

I've worked a lot of refactoring on my old code and I noticed that I have created strings in two ways:
*First way -* using a new operator:

`String stringA = new String ("String A");` 
*Second way -* using literal:

```
String stringB = "String B";
```

Could anyone explain which of these way is better and why?

Comment: This is one of the cases where the simplest, cleanest, most readable code is also the best performance code. Certainly use the second way in all new code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short: **A better way is second statement**.

**Explanation:**
String is immutable in Java. Regarding the fact that object can always be reused if it is immutable, you should always avoid first statement because this statement needlessly  creates a new String instance always when it is executed.

Instead of this you should always use second statement because it uses a single String instance and it is guaranteed that the object will be reused.

I highly recommend the book: Effective Java, Second Edition by Joshua Bloch.
More info for your question and some benchmark results you can find here -
[Effective Java - Same method invocation time despite creating multiple instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791836/effective-java-same-method-invocation-time-despite-creating-multiple-instances). 
I hope that facts are helpfull.

Comment: Thanks Bosko for clear explanation and useful links. That help me a lot.